# custom query cakephp3

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, find, cakephp-3.0

Im trying to create a custom find but i still got an error.

code in controller

```
class AnunciosController extends AppController
{

public function listaServicos($id = null)
{
    $anuncios = $this->loadModel('Anuncios')->find('ByService', ['service_id' => $id]);

    die(print_r($anuncios));

    //$anuncios = $this->paginate($this->Anuncios);
    //$this->set(compact('anuncios'));
    //$this->set('_serialize', ['anuncios']);
}
}
```

code in tableModel:

```
        class AnunciosTable extends Table
    {

 public function findByService(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
        {
            print_r($options);
            $query = $this->find()
                ->select(['id','user_prof_id'])
                ->where(['service_id'=>$options['service_id']]);
            $return = $query->execute();

            return $return;
        }
}
```

And after run, the return is this error:

Array ( [service_id] => 7 )

```
Cake\Database\Statement\CallbackStatement Object ( [_callback:protected] => Cake\Database\FieldTypeConverter Object ( [_typeMap:protected] => Array ( [Anuncios__id] => Cake\Database\Type\IntegerType Object ( [_name:protected] => integer ) [Anuncios__user_prof_id] => Cake\Database\Type\IntegerType Object ( [_name:protected] => integer ) ) [_driver:protected] => Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql Object ( [connected] => 1 ) ) [_statement:protected] => Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement Object ( [_logger:protected] => DebugKit\Database\Log\DebugLog Object ( [_queries:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [query] => SELECT Facs.id AS `Facs__id`, Facs.name AS `Facs__name`, Facs.description AS `Facs__description`, Facs.created AS `Facs__created`, Facs.modified AS `Facs__modified` FROM facs Facs [took] => 2 [rows] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [query] => SELECT Servicos.id AS `Servicos__id`, Servicos.category_id AS `Servicos__category_id`, Servicos.name AS `Servicos__name`, Servicos.created AS `Servicos__created`, Servicos.modified AS `Servicos__modified` FROM servicos Servicos [took] => 1 [rows] => 53 ) [2] => Array ( [query] => SELECT Anuncios.id AS `Anuncios__id`, Anuncios.user_prof_id AS `Anuncios__user_prof_id` FROM anuncios Anuncios WHERE service_id = 7 [took] => 1 [rows] => 0 ) ) [_logger:protected] => [_connectionName:protected] => default [_totalTime:protected] => 4 [_totalRows:protected] => 61 ) [_compiledParams:protected] => Array ( [c0] => 7 ) [_statement:protected] => Cake\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement Object ( [_statement:protected] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT Anuncios.id AS `Anuncios__id`, Anuncios.user_prof_id AS `Anuncios__user_prof_id` FROM anuncios Anuncios WHERE service_id = :c0 ) [_driver:protected] => Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql Object ( [connected] => 1 ) [_hasExecuted:protected] => [_bufferResults:protected] => 1 ) [_driver:protected] => Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql Object ( [connected] => 1 ) [_hasExecuted:protected] => 1 ) [_driver:protected] => Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql Object ( [connected] => 1 ) [_hasExecuted:protected] => ) 1
```

Can anyone helpme? What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `loadModel()` incorrectly. Instead of:-

```
$anuncios = $this->loadModel('Anuncios')->find('ByService', ['service_id' => $id]);
```

You should be doing:-

```
$this->loadModel('Anuncios');
$anuncios = $this->Anuncios->find('byService', ['service_id' => $id]);
```

[`loadModel()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake%5CController%5CController::loadModel) attaches the model to your current controller (same as in CakePHP 2). You also need to call your [custom finder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods) as `byService` (lowercase 'b') not `ByService`.

Comment: I changed the code as you said, but i still getting the same error. :/

Comment: more tips, for what could be the problem?